# Cache jQuery Selectors to a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

Based on code similar to the below javaScript, I am wanting to be able to use `panelDNS.cache.propertyName` to **cache** several commonly used jQuery Selectors

The problem is it seems I need to wrap it inside of `$(document).ready(function() { )` for it to work.

Im just learning JS so I am not sure how I can do this and keep my short  `panelDNS.cache` to access these values?

To clarify my question.  Since `panelDNS.cache` is not a `Function` that I can Call inside my `init` function, I need to figure out how to make sure the DOM is loaded before `panelDNS.cache` gets called or ran

```
var panelDNS = {

  unsavedChanges: false,

  init: function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      PanelDNS.events();
    });
  },


  cache: {
    dnsTitleId: $("#dnsTitle"),
    translation: {
      absolute: 0,
      relative: 0,
      sinceDirectionChange: 0,
      percentage: 0
    }
  },

  events: {

  }

}
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem entirely but the thing is that you have to wait for the DOM to load before you can execute your jQuery selectors on any DOM elements. It is only after that point that you can store the result of that selectors in some kind of global object. What is it that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am asking, how I can make sure panelDNS.cache.xxx only gets called after the DOM s loaded"

You are responsible for that. Make sure that your application code only gets executed after the DOM is loaded by kicking off the app in the document ready function:

```
$(function(){
    //Your kickoff code
});
```

Comment: Ok makes sense, so if I do that, then I should no longer require it also being ran inside my current `init` function?

Comment: If you call your panelDNS.init function from within the document ready function, you will no longer need the document ready call in the init function.